# valums file uploader: size value for onComplete, list item hooks, and file overwrite options

Tags: php, json, jquery, file-upload

I am using Valum's file uploader:
http://valums.com/ajax-upload/

To upload files via PHP.

1.
I would like to use the size of the file upload in the onComplete call,
but I do no know how to get the size of the file just uploaded.
I know how to get the fileName using this,

```
onComplete: function(id, fileName, responseJSON){
    fileName //is the filename, but what about the file size?
}
```

But I do not know how to get the file name (from the JavaScript, through PHP I can but that isn't much help here).

2.
Also during the onComplete call, I would like to be able to access the list item `<li>` that the file upload script creates below the upload button.
When I inspect them with fire-bug I can only see that they have a class, and not an ID.
I want to hide each one once I have complete the other stuff in my onComplete, but do not want to also hide the rest of the files in the queue.

3.
When a file is being uploaded, If the file already exists I would like a message to pop-up and ask the user if they want to overwrite the file. I would like there to then be 3 options,
one where the file is not overwritten and the upload is cancelled, one where the file is not overwritten, but the new file is uploaded and a version number is added (eg, test.txt becomes testv2.txt, similar to the default now), and three where the old file is overwritten with the new file.

I can probably figure out the PHP to this quite easily, but what I need help with is understanding how the variables are passed between the pages using json/jquery/ajax/etc.

Any help with any of these questions would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. php.php line 301

   return array('success'=>true);

you can add your own values in here eg

return array('success'=>true,'foo'=>bar);

and retrieve them on the front

```
onComplete: function(id, fileName, responseJSON){
    alert(responseJSON["foo"]);
}
```

1. Add an id to the list item
2. use onSubmit: to call an ajax request to check if the file exists

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

echo a json from server with the data you need, then use parseJSON in OnComplete function, thats a javascript object obtained from parse the response from the server.

Comment: How do I echo a json from the server? and then what is the syntax for it in the onComplete